# Is OpenAL open-source? Where is the source code?

Tags: openal

Is OpenAL open-source?

I need to change something in it and I can't find the source code of it.

I checked [the official OpenAL website](https://www.openal.org/) too, but found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Open" in OpenAL doesn't mean an open *source*. As in case of OpenGL, the main idea was an open *specification* of the library implemented by various hardware vendors.

OpenAL has been initially pushed by Creative to promote hardware features of their Audio cards, but nowadays the most active project is an open source library **OpenAL-soft** under LGPL:
https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft

Documentation of this project has a weak reference to an older one:

> It's forked from the open-sourced Windows version available originally from openal.org's SVN repository (now defunct)

The original project is defunct for a long time, but you may find a mirror on GitHub. Cannot say if it is of any use - I would better stick to OpenAL soft and consider the old project only for archeological researches:
https://github.com/rpavlik/openal-svn-mirror

Comment: "Open" in OpenAL **does** also mean as in *open source*, Loki had quite the ambitions. It's just that after their demise, it was only Creative to care for the standard.. and in their hardware lock-in glory they certainly didn't want the Sample Implementation to compete with them. OpenAL-soft is just a continuation of that original spirit (the other linked repository is just an older version of it, also mixed with all the sources of the Creative tree like the Windows router and directsound wrapper, and some tool and doc)

Comment: Thanks for historical details - it is difficult today to find a comprehensive information how OpenAL was originated.